# CSS-mediaqueries.js doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser, responsive-design, media-queries

We're using css3-mediaqueries.js (http://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/) to make this responsive website (http://webdesigndordrecht.elephantlabs.nl/) work in IE8 and lower. However, it does not seem to work.

The file is linked up correctly and fires (we implemented an alert in the library to check), but when resizing IE8 and lower, it does not fire. We used the exact same file like we did for some other responsive websites we've made...

HTML and CSS validation were checked as well, CSS doesn't validate because of some vendor tags, but I can't imagine that being the problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it - this one might come in handy for someone working on this as well:

CSS3-mediaqueries.js **will only work on directly included CSS links** - we had our media queries in an imported stylesheet (via @import).